# Notification if a member cancels their membership?

Tags: civimember

Is there a way to have Civicrm notify us, via email or any other way, everytime a member cancels their membership/auto renewal?

thank you for the help.

Comment: I would think CiviRules plus https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi perhaps as a first step.

Answer (score 2):

As petednz suggested the CiviRules extension should be able to help you with this. Are your memberships cancelled from a profile? Or in the CiviCRM user interface? Then it will certainly help you. You should test first, I do not know if people used it for cancelling memberships yet.

The CiviRules extension is here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules
Documentation is here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/